# Firebase Crash Reporting doesn't deobfuscate crash reports

Tags: android, mapping, obfuscation, android-proguard, firebase-crash-reporting

My App has Proguard enabled which obfuscates the code. The problem is that, even though I've uploaded the Proguard's mapping.txt file, crash reports are still obfuscated.

I've intentionally caused the crash in orded to test the deobfuscation. The crash happens in DiscoverFragment in method `onCreateView`

Here is the report summary:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{co.bstorm.lv_android/co.bstorm.lv_android.home.DiscoverActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference

android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2665)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Here you can clearly see that the code is still obfuscated:

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke a virtual method on a null object reference

co.bstorm.lv_android.home.DiscoverFragment.a (DiscoverFragment.java)
android.support.v4.app.Fragment.b (Fragment.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.u (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.a (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.g (FragmentManagerImpl.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.b (FragmentController.java)
android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java)
android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1248)
android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:6696)
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2628)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2726)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1477)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:154)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6119)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:886)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on? I can't determine whether the problem is on my side or if it's the issue with the Firebase.

Comment: does the deobfuscation of stack trace work when you run `retrace` locally e.g. `retrace.sh  -verbose  ./app/build/outputs/mapping/release/mapping.txt crash.txt`?

Comment: Did you upload the mappings file *before* the very first time a particular crash occurred?

Comment: @DougStevenson I've uploaded the mapping file before the crash occurred but I don't think that should matter.

Comment: @zivko It does *very much* matter that you upload the mappings before the crash happens.  Crashes won't be deobfuscated unless there is a mappings file found for the version of the app that generated the crash.